# UK visitor entry clearance application refused: impact on future travel

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, visa-refusals

I am an Indian citizen living in Poland for the past 4 years for business. I never visited UK before.

I applied for UK visa few months ago in Warsaw to visit London for just 3 days, carelessly missed attaching couple of company documents related to my employment. After a month of processing, I received "refusal of entry clearance letter" which  I summarize:

1. I have not provided evidence of employment and proved my source of income/salary (I only gave company registration document proving I am the CEO of company but missed attaching salary documents.). Because of this made them think that I am going to UK to find job and employment and I won't come back (which I concur). But they never cared to ask for missing documents, immediately gave the refusal decision which is terribly disappointing!
2. They say that despite my extensive travel history, the onus is on me to prove that I will leave UK. (I proved strong ties to my country India and second home Poland) with the number of travel stamps in and out. I am a frequent traveler to Europe. Also I sent them travel itinerary for 3 days, booking confirmed for hotel for 3 days, not enough?)
3. It also says that I cannot appeal the decision.

This is very disappointing taking into consideration that you pay GBP 180, they keep your passport for 1 month before making a decision, can't believe is such a long time.

I had shown them enough money, which is no problem being a business owner and I never had any intention of taking up jobs (why would I being a boss look for a job?), clearly this worked against me. I never been to UK before, so I thought I could visit London for 3 days.

I decided not to appeal (I had all the reasons stacked up to appeal through UK court within 60 days, money not an issue).

I see a black denial stamp in the backside page of my passport.

Now, all my hopes and travel plans of visiting UK, Scotland are destroyed and I vowed not to apply for UK anymore, as it was such a frustrating experience. I don't have patience to wait for 1+ month to reapply for UK visa. Even India is more advanced, issues e-visa these days much faster in about 3 days. What is killing me is despite living in Europe for 4 years, holding Schengen visa, UK visa should be easy, but I paid dearly.

1. Will UK denial also work against me applying for visa to any other countries?
2. What are the chances of getting UK visa again?

Comment: Consider asking those questions separately, it's a little broad

Comment: It happens a lot, but hard to know the implications without knowing what they wrote. Can you edit your question to include the text of your refusal notice? You can get a much more focused answer to your question if you include the 'legal' reasons for your refusal. Close voting as 'unclear'.

Comment: In general, refusals caused by your failing to show evidence (e.g., you did not show enough to suggest that you are likely to leave) are no problem: just apply again with the deficiencies in your earlier application corrected.  Without more specific information about your case, though, we can't know whether that is the case here.

Comment: Phoog, please add that as answer :)

Comment: They do not contact applicants for missing documents.  You have added some content explaining the refusal, would you please add the exact text?  Otherwise a generic answer like 'provide the missing documents and apply again' will have to do.

Comment: @pbu I don't have enough personal experience or sources to back up my claim as authoritatively as should be the case for an answer especially given Gayot Fow's having taken an interest in the question.  He is far more knowledgeable and experienced in these matters than I.  You would do well to follow his advice and add more detail to your question.

Comment: @Gayot Fow Thanks for the input. I have the original document paper at home (currently traveling) so decided a short version of my story. I have decided that i will not visit UK again ever.

Comment: @pbu, it remains a good idea to bring this question to a professional conclusion because there are lots of people who will find it helpful to read vis-a-vis their own refusal or application.

Comment: @GayotFow Of course, people should know the truth and how innocent persons like me are a victim of visa-bureaucracy.  I will post the exact wordings when i am back in Europe. I completely respect the decision, what i am only against is, they just take the money, dont care to check the documents at collection centre, dont care to ask for missing documents, 3 weeks processing time (way too long retaining my passport, no way to travel) and then denial with no way to appeal :(  Why is UK is not moving to e-visa system? Because of this UK is missing millions of tourists due to slow visa regime.

Comment: @pbu, I look forward to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its common as you also missed attaching the required documents it happens.i would suggest you to re-apply with those documents missed, chance of getting approved is more if it valid. it won't affect your future applications